# How do I create custom intent in siri

Tags: ios, sirikit

I know siri provides limited Intents and we have to add our app to domain to be able take input from siri.

But I would like to create my own intent for the users to access my app via siri.

I couldn't find much support for this anywhere  ? any helpful pointers are welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update

Now you can create custom intents and use them with Siri Shortcuts. Here is a simplified tutorial by Ray Wenderlich

https://www.raywenderlich.com/6462-siri-shortcuts-tutorial-in-ios-12

or you can prefer

[This article for beginners](https://medium.com/@pietropizzi/a-beginners-guide-to-developing-custom-intent-siri-shortcuts-for-ios-12-a3627b7011af)

For more details, you should prefer Apple's official documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit

### Outdated Answer

You can't create a custom intent for now. Maybe in later versions, they can add support for custom intents. Maybe they don't. With their current approach, Apple holds all the control over, intent(operation) types, data, privacy, etc. I'm not sure they will change that.

If you really need custom voice commands, you can implement it inside your application(not out of the app like Siri). There are alternatives like

[Apple's AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer)

[Apple's Speech](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech)

[IBM's Watson](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk)

[Nuance Speech Kit](https://github.com/NuanceDev/speechkit-ios-sample-swift)

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Still the case?

Comment: It's no longer the case, iOS 12 allows custom intents.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom intent as of iOS 12. It is quite a complicated process, but there are some tutorials available that can help you out.

I think Apple's [WWDC example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/211/) is a good starting point.